# Slicknav overhang on top of wrapper

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, menu

How I could make the orange menu come in line with the wrapper? I've tried playing around with the slicknav.css but to no avail.

Here is the image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Slicknav code

```
/*
    Mobile Menu Core Style
*/

.slicknav_btn { position: relative; display: block; vertical-align: middle; float: right; padding: 0.438em 0.625em 0.438em 0.625em; line-height: 1.125em; cursor: pointer; }
.slicknav_menu  .slicknav_menutxt { display: block; line-height: 1.188em; float: left; }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon { float: left; margin: 0.188em 0 0 0.438em; }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_no-text { margin: 0 }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar { display: block; width: 1.125em; height: 0.125em; -webkit-border-radius: 1px; -moz-border-radius: 1px; border-radius: 1px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
.slicknav_btn .slicknav_icon-bar + .slicknav_icon-bar { margin-top: 0.188em }
.slicknav_nav { clear: both }
.slicknav_nav ul,
.slicknav_nav li { display: block }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_arrow { font-size: 0.8em; margin: 0 0 0 0.4em; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item { display: block; cursor: pointer; }
.slicknav_nav a { display: block }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a { display: inline }
.slicknav_menu:before,
.slicknav_menu:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.slicknav_menu:after { clear: both }
/* IE6/7 support */
.slicknav_menu { *zoom: 1 }

/* 
    User Default Style
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of the menu.
*/

.slicknav_menu {
    font-size:16px;

}
/* Button */
.slicknav_btn {
    margin: 5px 5px 6px;    
    text-decoration:none;   
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);   
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;  
    background-color: #222222;
}
/* Button Text */
.slicknav_menu  .slicknav_menutxt { 
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;  
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px #000;    
}
/* Button Lines */
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.slicknav_menu {
    background:#FF6414;
}

.slicknav_nav {
    color:#fff;
    margin:0;   
    padding:0;
    font-size:0.875em;
}
.slicknav_nav, .slicknav_nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slicknav_nav ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 0 20px;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item {
    padding:5px 10px;
    margin:2px 5px;
}
.slicknav_nav a{
    padding:5px 10px;
    margin:2px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item:hover {
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#fff; 
}
.slicknav_nav a:hover{
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#222;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_txtnode {
     margin-left:15px;   
}
```

Menu code

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Personal Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Technical Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the main menu display:none when the browser width gets to a certain size, then the slicknav pops up.

Comment: make a http://jsfiddle.net/ we need to see some code :)

Comment: I've tried doing that but it's difficult, what sort of code? I can just post it here?

Comment: enough code to be able to replicate the problem. Otherwise we can only guess what the issue is.. Yes you can post it here. Just edit your question.

Comment: Done, i've left out the media queries as I don't think that's the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LGSon's answer will work if the SlickNav is to exist to outside the wrapper, however, it may be easier for you to prepend the SlickNav to the top of the wrapper.

```
$('#menu').slicknav({
    prependTo:'#wrapper'
});
```

Where "#wrapper" is the selector for your wrapper element. This will allow the SlickNav to remain within the bounds of the wrapper with the other content. If that is not ideal, modifying the margin of ".slicknav_menu" to match the wrapper should be sufficient.